# Hosting ASP.NET Inside Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Yes, I know it is not the intention of Silverlight to host ASP.NET and that the namespaces/classes have been removed, but I have a small personal/pet project where Cassini-like hosting functionality (localhost only is fine) from within Silverlight would be a slick feature.

Can this be made to work somehow?  What is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do it because it's not possible to create a listening TCP socket. You can only create client TCP connections.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping to hear, but can't argue with it.  Thanks.